# How to call section one by one after clicked on button and previous section will hide?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have 3 `sections` and one `button`.

1. When the user clicks on the `button` for the first time, the contents of the first `section` should be displayed.
2. When the user clicks on the same button for the second time, the second section should be displayed and the first section should be hidden.
3. Same thing on section third section.

Please help me in this.

```
<section id="one" style="display:none;">
    <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s,</p>
</section>

<section id="two" style="display:none;">
    <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</p>
</section>

<section id="three" style="display:none;">
    <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s,Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s</p>
</section>

<input type="submit" onclick="checkDiv();">

<script>
    function checkDiv(){
        document.getElementById('one').style.display = "block";
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you include jquery to your project you could do it like so:

```js
function next() {
  var current = $('.current');
  var next = current.next('.m-div:first');
  
  // loop back to the first div
  if(next.length == 0) { next = $('#one'); }
  
  current.removeClass('current');
  next.addClass('current');
}
```

```css
.m-div {display: none;}

.m-div.current {
  display: block;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section class="m-div current" id="one" >
<p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s,</p>
</section>

<section class="m-div" id="two">
<p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</p>
</section>


<section class="m-div" id="three">
<p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s,Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s</p>
</section>

<input type="submit" onclick="next();">
```

Comment: Thanks Mr.WalksAway, Its working perfectly for  my project .

Answer (score 0):

You can use the accordian of jquery

https://jqueryui.com/accordion/

Comment: Mr.Harshit.I have to hide previous section.I don't want to use accordion

Answer (score 0):

Here's a pretty clean way to do it with pure JS:

```js
//Wrap your function in a self-invocing funtion to have private variables outside the function that gets executed on each click. This prevents from the elem value being reset everytime the function is called.
var checkDiv=(function(){
    //Create a couple private variables:
    var sections = ['one','two','three'],
        elem = -1;
    //The returned function will be executed when checkDiv is called:
    return function(e){
        //check if there's more content to show:
        if(elem<sections.length){
            //first hide the current element (unless there's nothing yet to hide):
            if(elem>-1) document.getElementById(sections[elem]).style.display = "none";
            //then switch to the next element:
            elem++;
            //and display the new element:
            document.getElementById(sections[elem]).style.display = "block";
            //as a bonus, you can disable the button once there's no more content to show:
            if(elem===sections.length-1) e.currentTarget.disabled=true;
        }
    }
})();
```

```html
<section id="one" style="display:none;">
    <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s,</p>
</section>

<section id="two" style="display:none;">
    <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</p>
</section>

<section id="three" style="display:none;">
    <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s,Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s</p>
</section>

<input type="button" onclick="checkDiv(event)" value="next">
```

Comment: Mr.llpo, loop is going continue. how to stop that because after 3rd section its again goes to 1 section that i don't want.

Comment: Oh, I misunderstood what you wanted. Just a second, I'll fix it.

Comment: Mr.llpo, Can you help  me little more .In first section  i am using check box <input type="checkbox"  required /> if i clicked on submit than its going to next section .Why it's not taking required validation?Please help me in this also

Comment: Are they inside the same form?

Comment: Yes.In first section i have checkbox. Like term and condition check box

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112412/discussion-between-hybreeder-and-ilpo-oksanen).